# Create a number format with criteria by using a loop every row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, format

I want to make a number format with criteria if USD = 4 Digits, IDR = 0 Digits, JPY = 2 Digits using macros in excel because there are a lot of rows

[image: Sample]

Thanks for the help

I've used this module but it doesn't work

```
Sub LoopRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    For Each cell In rng
        If Range("a1").Value = "IDR" Then
        Range("b:b").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    ElseIf Range("a1").Value = "JPY" Then
        Range("b:b").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Else: Range("b:b").NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000"
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`For Each cell In rng` already loops trough specific cell, no need to specify later `Range("a1")`. Furthermore, you are looping only trough A1, I think yoi mean `cell`

Also, `Range("b:b").NumberFormat` will change the format of the **whole** column. I think you want `cell.Offset(0,1).NumberFormat` or `Range("B" & cell.row)`

Probably you want  something like this:

```
Sub LoopRange()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "IDR" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "JPY" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000"
    End If
Next cell

Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting as well:

[image]